# SetTimeout functionality not taking place

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

In the a.js file
I have a function called as:

```
Move(coordinates,callback) {
//Move the cursor from point A to point B based on the coordinates as parameter
});
```

In the b.js file
I am calling this function since I want to see the cursor move slowly after every 30 seconds.
This is the call:

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
setTimeout(Move(inputcordinates,events = {
  //someevents
}),30000);
}
```

Problem is when the page is loaded , the function is getting executed and the cursor has already moved 6 times to the position,
The delay is not happening in front of my eyes but the functionality is executed for sure.

What could be the problem in the code  shown above?
I have increased the code to about 120000 also still no effect.

Comment: You're calling the `Move()` function and assign the return value of it as the first parameter of the `setTimeout`. Wrap it in an anonymous function `setTimeout(function() { Move(...) }, ...`. And you should adjust the timeout parameter in each round of the loop. Otherwise all six timeouts will fire at the same time. Something like `30000 * (i + 1)`

Answer (score 4):

It is because you call your function directly. You must write it like this :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    Move(inputcordinates,events = {
       //someevents
    });
}, 30000)
```

Comment: Yeah it is the solution....But the problem here is all the timeouts will fire at the same time.From the question that is not the case.

Comment: As mentioned in Andreas comment make it as 30000*(i+1)

Comment: Which gives time inconsistency between intervals.That is why I have used Set Interval Method instead of set Timeout

Answer (score 0):

You can also use setInterval for this which is easy to achieve and clear 
Try as below..

```
 var i = 0;
 var myVar;
        function getData() {

            myVar = setInterval(function () { Move(x,y)() }, 2000);

        }
        function Move(coordinates,callback){
            i++;
            alert('Hi');
            if (i == 5) {
                alert('5 times');
                clearInterval(myVar);
            }

        }
```